# ActionbarSherlock fixed tabs with ViewPager?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-viewpager, android-tabs

I'm using ActionbarSherlock Tabs navigation with ViewPager. **I want three fixed tabs on the whole width of a screen.**

But tabs don't take the whole width:

[image]

The code is standart. It's a little bit too long to paste it here, so [it is on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/mTpVsq0p). ActionbarSherlock 4.2.

**How to scretch tabs on the whole width?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want three fixed tabs on the whole width of a screen.

You will need to find an implementation of tabs for `ViewPager` (e.g., `PagerTabStrip` from the Android Support package, or a tab implementation from ViewPagerIndicator) and modify it to look the way you want.

Comment: I'll use ViewPagerIndicator instead of ActionbarSherlock tabs.

Answer (score 0):

If Actionbarsherlock tabs been used, it will support in all versions.